# VIM suddenly highlighted the spaces in my file how do I turn this off?

Tags: vimrc

[image: Vim highlight some unused space in the file]

I just recently used Vim as my code editor. It was working fine then suddenly when I opened a file to edit my code this happens. When I open the file nothing is highlighted. But when I start scrolling down the file then scroll back up the highlight shows up. Resizing the window also removes the highlight but goes back whenever I scroll the file up and down.

Comment: This is likely a terminal/colorscheme problem. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, You are correct. I tried running Vim without the vimrc, the highlight still shows up. How do I proceed on fixing this?

Comment: What is `TERM` ? Is it properly set?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was able to solve the issue by setting termguicolors in my vimrc.

Comment: sounds like a self-answer to me